# Calculate circle intersections with varying number of circles

Tags: python, geometry, sympy

I've looked at several SO posts related to this question, but all seem to deal with a FIXED number of circles.  My problem set involves calculating all the intersections of all circles in multiple dictionary values of varying length.

The trilaterationSet dictionary key is an ID, values are tuples of lat, lon, and radius in meters.  My code is below.  For some reason the intersection points it returns do not match my manual plots on Google Earth.

The ultimate goal is to cluster the intersections, then find the center of the densest cluster of points.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
import math
from math import pi, cos, sin, atan2
import numpy as np
import geopy
import numpy as np
import json
import csv
from sympy import geometry
from sympy.geometry import Point, Circle, Polygon
import itertools

# key = idnumber, value = tuple (lat, lon, radius in meters)    
trilaterationSet =[{'ID1': [(41.0994, 69.035, 535), (41.0994, 69.04, 333), (41.0994, 69.045, 535), (41.103, 69.035, 433), (41.103, 69.04, 111)]}, 
                  {'ID2': [(41.1102, 69.06, 610), (41.1102, 69.065, 580), (41.1138, 69.06, 274)]}]


def circle_intersections(dataDict):
    '''Finds all intersections for all sensor detection circles.'''

    # set up an empty list to hold circles
    circles = []
    
    # empty list to hold intersections
    all_intersections = []
    
    # iterates through dictionary 
    for key, value in dataDict.items(): 
        for tup in value:
            
            # converts lat/long/dist to radians IOT get all data in same units
            radLat = float(tup[0]) * pi / 180
            radLon = float(tup[1]) * pi / 180
            radDist = int(tup[2]) / 6378000
            
            # draws circle and appends to circles list
            circles.append(Circle(Point(radLon, radLat), radDist))
        
        # empty list to hold intersections when converted back to lat/lon
        unRad_intersections = []
        
        # gets all combinations of circles  and calculates their intersects
        for c1, c2 in itertools.combinations(circles, 2):
            all_intersections += c1.intersection(c2)
        
        # converts radians back to lat/lon 
        for p in all_intersections:
            unRad = p * 180 / pi
            unRad_intersections.append(unRad)
        
        # converts sympy rationals back to floats for final lat/long data
        finalPoints = [tuple(p.evalf()) for p in unRad_intersections]

        print(finalPoints)
        

circle_intersections(trilaterationSet)
```

Comment: `circle_intersections` accepts a dictionary but `trilaterationSet` is a list. Could you also post your expected values?

Comment: You're correct.  When deployed, I run a large set of dictionaries through the function from a separate file.  I pulled a couple of items out of that file and made the `trilaterationSet` for this example.

Comment: My expected outputs for the first item in `trilaterationSet` are below:
( 41.096408°,  69.039995°), ( 41.099175°,  69.036047°), ( 41.100330°,  69.038733°), ( 41.101978°,  69.039996°), ( 41.102022°,  69.039652°), ( 41.102302°,  69.039013°), ( 41.103278°,  69.038738°), ( 41.103992°,  69.039993°), ( 41.103285°,  69.041275°), ( 41.102298°,  69.040982°), ( 41.102508°,  69.040134°), ( 41.102383°,  69.039996°), ( 41.102401°,  69.040116°), ( 41.102290°,  69.040082°), ( 41.102016°,  69.040340°), ( 41.102295°,  69.029932°)